# Why does Dictionary[index] throws a KeyNotFoundException but Hashtable[index] doesn't?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable

Any idea why this behaviour is different?

Comment: Would like to know the same X-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the [answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/04/26/120438.aspx).

> The primary reason Dictionary
>   throws is that there is no "error"
>   value that works over any V. 
>   Hashtable is able to return null
>   because the key is always a reference
>   type.

Comment: Worth noting: `HashTable` allows to write unsafer code in this way. `var ht = new Hashtable() {{"A", null}};
            string aVal = (string)ht["A"];
            string bVal = (string)ht["B"];` Both return `null`, you can't differentiate between a valid value or a non existent key. At least the bug is hidden and silent which is even worse, the dictionary will tell you with an exception.

Answer (score 6):

So there will be no ambiguity between when the value of dictionary[key] stores a null value and when the key doesn't exist.  Hashtable[key] will return null if it stores null or the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

The primary reason Dictionary throws is political - had several options to preserve efficiency and ease of use. It actually provides a method (TryGetValue) which clearly demonstrates that claims about alleged "inability" to return sensible value are false. TryGetValue however forces distinctively awkward syntax to do exactly what indexer could have done easily.

C# templates provide easy way for constructing separate implementations for reference and value semantics and there are two other facilities for seamless handling of missing objects with value semantice which are used by tempates and some operators (default and nullable). Meaning that there was no rational reason to break the semantics of the hashtable.

It's a long terms political struggle between the academic notion of a collection which insists that everyone has to go through "do you have it" checks and real-life fact that such artificial procedure is inefficient and breaks thread safety - in principle (it breaks thread-safety of otherwise safe implementations by making acces non-atomic).

Comment: I wish the `TryXX` pattern specified that the method should return `default(T)` in case of failure, but use an `out bool` parameter to indicate whether it worked.  This would allow `book ok; var theValue = myDict.TryGetValue(myKey, out ok); if (ok) ...`.  Such a pattern would allow for both type inference and covariance, and also facilitate the case where the desired behavior for a non-existent key is to assume a value of `default(T)`.

Comment: "TryGetValue however forces distinctively awkward syntax to do exactly what indexer could have done easily." - This could not be more wrong. Simply indexing does not allow checking if a key mapping exists neither in case of structs, nor when a null is allowed as a valid value. The only way for an index to allow such a thing would be by returning two values, which is exactly what TryGetValue does, and also kind of what the index does if you consider it throws an exception when the key mapping doesn't exist.